# Unknown return type in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I am going through a Javascript code and encountered the following construct which I am not able to comprehend.

```
case "RED":
     return (0, h.default)(e);
```

Please explain what this return type is?

Comment: that looks like it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The void operator evaluates the appended method but then returns undefined, the return value here is undefined, no matter what `(0, h.default)(e)` returns.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void:

```js
console.log(void 2 == '2'); // (void 2) == '2', returns false
console.log(void (2 == '2')); // void (2 == '2'), returns undefined
```